# PySide не находит плагины форматов изображений

Tags: pyside

Если запросить список поддерживаемых форматов:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
image_formats = [str(_) for _ in QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()]
print(image_formats)
```

то, вернутся не все (jpg/jpeg, например нет):

```
['bmp', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'png', 'ppm', 'xbm', 'xpm']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке PySide есть папка `plugins` со всеми нужными плагинами, но их нужно вручную добавить в `QCoreApplication` (или его наследникам) методом `addLibraryPath`:

```
def load_pyside_plugins():
    """
    Функция загружает Qt плагины.
    
    """
    
    import PySide
    import os

    qApp = PySide.QtGui.QApplication.instance()

    for plugins_dir in [os.path.join(p, "plugins") for p in PySide.__path__]:
        qApp.addLibraryPath(plugins_dir)
```

Проверяем:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

load_pyside_plugins()
image_formats = [str(_) for _ in QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()]
print(image_formats)
```

Консоль:

```
['bmp', 'gif', 'ico', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'mng', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'png', 'ppm', 'tga', 'tif', 'tiff', 'xbm', 'xpm']
```